# ¿Como puedo convertir un String a un long en Drools

Tags: java, string, eclipse, drools

Numero ya viene desde una clase en java pero es un String necesito convertirlo en un long en Drools

```
declare Numero
     Numero : String
     long dsNumeroFactura = new Long(dsNumeroFactura).longValue();
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya intentaste con:

```
Long.parseLong("64738")
```

parseLong convierte cadenas a Longs

Comment: sii ya intente pero no funciona ¿ alguna otra forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Debes convertir tu string a Long

```
Long.valueOf(Numero)
```